# Write/Read resources with System.Resources.ResourceManager

Tags: vb.net, resources, byte, resourcemanager

I want to be able to write and read resources with the ResourceManager class in Visual Basic .NET (2010) instead of using the Win32 API (UpdateResources)

I tried to first read resources like this:

```
Dim ResMan As New Resources.ResourceManager("Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
Dim Bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(ResMan.GetObject("Bytes"), Byte())
ResMan.ReleaseAllResources()
```

And it worked, but then I tried to write resources, but it didn't work at all, I kept getting errors, and honestly my code was so dirty I felt ashamed.

So basically I need a way to write resources using ResourceManager.

Comment: you cant do that, they are read only.  That is why there is a `GetObject`, but no `SetObject`.  The errors were likely something like it being readonly, no?

Comment: Ah, I see! Well thanks for the information. I'm just wondering, how are you really supposed to write resources then?

Comment: save them somewhere...the resources you add/have in VS are compiled into the app, so you cant add to them or even delete them.

Comment: But, you __can__ write resources using the API, so shouldn't there be a way to write resources __without__ using the API too?

Comment: thats WIN32, not .NET.  if you tried writing to a .NET assembly you would likely invalidate it and prevent it from loading.

Comment: I see, so bascially it differs from native applications and managed. This has been very informative, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [resx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx). Standalone resource files that can be read from and written to. You can use simple obfuscation if you don't want the data readable.